# MongoDB-Express: Cannot get the client/db out of connect function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am separating the connect function of MongoDB to a separate module, so that the mongoDB connection is reusable. The issue is, I could not get the client/DB variable outside the connect function. It shows undefined.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var _client;
var mongoURL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

module.exports = {
    connectToMongoServer: (callback) => {
        MongoClient.connect(mongoURL,{ useNewUrlParser: true },function(err,client){
            _client = client;
            return callback(err);
        });
    },
    getClient: () => {
        return _client;
    }
};
```

Within the connect function, the _client details contains the information, but if I return it using getClient, it shows **undefined**.

MongoDB - v3.6.5

Node - v9.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made up a snippet which should work the same ad your code, and it works.
So I think the problem is how you are calling your function `getClient()`; are you sure you are calling it **after** it get connected?

```js
var _client;

function someAsyncFunc(callback) {
 setTimeout(() => callback(false, 'client'), 500);
}

const file = {
  connectToMongoServer: (callback) => {
   someAsyncFunc(function(err, client) {
      _client = client;
      
      return callback(err);
    });
  },
  
  getClient: () => {
    return _client;
  }
};

console.log('display one :', file.getClient());

file.connectToMongoServer((err) => {
  console.log('display error :', err);
  
  console.log('display two :', file.getClient());
});
```

Comment: Well I  checked back after you said. I am calling it before it gets connected. In my code, at top level: var client = mongoUtil.getClient(). What happened was the parser automatically replaced it before calling the actual function. Thanks